# Searching encrypted field in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, security, encryption

I'm attempting to query an encrypted field in postgres using "pgp_sym_encrypt". I'm running my test by setting all the first names in my table to an encrypted value:

```
update person set first_name = pgp_sym_encrypt('test', 'password');
```

Then selecting on it:

```
select * from person where first_name = pgp_sym_encrypt('test', 'password');
```

This returns no results.

If I change it to use the normal postgres encryption it will return all the rows in the table:

```
update person set first_name = encrypt('test', 'password', 'aes');
select * from person where first_name = encrypt('test', 'password', 'aes');
```

My current postgres version is: postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.0.
The first_name field in this case is a bytea field.

Does anyone know why this is not working using "pgp_sym_encrypt"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at PostgreSQL Documentation ([Appendix F.25. pgcrypto - F.25.3. PGP Encryption Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgcrypto.html#AEN159087)):

> The given password is hashed using a String2Key (S2K) algorithm. This is rather similar to crypt() algorithms — purposefully slow and **with random salt** — but it produces a full-length binary key.

(Emphasis mine.)

So the following gives different results every time you run it:

```
select pgp_sym_encrypt('test', 'password');
```

When testing the password use `pgp_sym_decrypt` instead, it can be tested like this:

```
select pgp_sym_decrypt(pgp_sym_encrypt('test', 'password'), 'password');
```

Comment: So if I wanted to do a search on data encrypted with a S2K algorithm would my only option be to setup a separate index on a secure hash of that data?

Comment: Search would be something like this? `select * from person where 'test' = pgp_sym_decrypt(first_name, 'password');`